# Identify if an object is forward or backward using GPS

Tags: math, gps, vectorization

Hello friends of the community. I've been developing a GPS app and the goal is to know the bus forward and backward of the bus that the user select in the app, and I've been thinking how to resolve this a quite while. All the buses are a GPS circuit tha works by Galileo protocol. There are a mathematic formula to resolve this? Or an mathematical arrangement? I try to use the latitude and logitude of the buses to resolve this, but is not working because of the different directions the buses take during their route.
I hope you can help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Do you have access to the velocity measurements that come from the GPS receiver? If so then this is trivial.

Comment: Yes, the GPS transmitter measures and sends the velocity of the buses.